# Last element of 2D array of strings overwriting previous array elements

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

```
void read_char_from_file(FILE *fp, int formatted)
{
    char sChar[16], eol;
    int col=0, row=0,ind=0,count=0;
    char *str2D[4][4]={{ "NULL" }};
    while ( (fscanf(fp, "%s%c", sChar,&eol)) != EOF)
    {
        if(eol!='\n')
        {
            str2D[row][col]=sChar;
            printf("Row: %d, Col: %d = %s\n",row, col,str2D[row][col]);
            col++;
        }
        else {
            str2D[row][col]=sChar;
            printf("Row: %d, Col: %d = %s\n",row, col,str2D[row][col]);
            row++;
            col=0;
        }
        str2D[row][col]=0;
    }

    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j <3; j++)
        printf("%s",str2D[i][j]);
    }

}
```

Above code is displaying last element of `str2D` overwriting all of the previous array contents. I need to copy `sChar` to 2-D array of strings.

Comment: `{{ "NULL" }};` != `{{ NULL }};`

Comment: what do you expect the contents of your 4 by 4 matrix to be after the initialization statement: `char *str2D[4][4]={{ "NULL" }};`.  I bet your expectations aren't met.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:

You are **not** copying the content *into* the memory location pointed to by `str2D[row][col]`, you're just making the pointer point to `sChar`. Thus, whatever is the latest content of the `sChar`, is being shown.

Long answer:

You have other issues. First,

- `{{ "NULL" }};` is not the same as  `{{ NULL }};`
- You are creating a 2-D array of pointers. Before you can store anything in those memory locations pointed to by the pointers, you need to make sure that they point to some valid locations.

Comment: How can I copy sChar into str2D ?

Comment: @FahadNaeem You need to 1) allocate memory to the pointers 2) use `strcpy()` to copy the content.